# Plotagem de gráficos com funções no Matplotlib 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

Preciso plotar um gráfico de área em que a altura `z` varia conforme uma função qualquer e o seu intervalo depende do **ponto inicial** e do **ponto final** informado. Encontrei o exemplo abaixo na internet, mas não sei como alterá-lo para que o gráfico obedeça as minhas condições impostas. Como posso proceder?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
t  = np.arange(1024)*1e-6
y1 = np.sin(t*2e3*np.pi) 
verts=[list(zip(t, y1))]

poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors = ['r','g','b'])
poly.set_alpha(0.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1024e-6)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Vamos começar do início. Para plotar o gráfico em 3D, devemos providenciar dados para o  eixo x, y, e z. Esses dados podem ser qualquer parâmetro que você passe para a função, após isso, devemos usar o comando:

```
plt.axes(projection = '3d')
```

Este comando cria uma base para definir o gráfico em 3D(x,y,z). Para passar os dados para este gráfico, primeiramente devemos referenciar o comando acima a uma variável e  devemos usar o comando a seguir para passar os valores em cada eixo.

```
grap = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
grap.scatter3D(x,y,z, s = '12')
```

o "scatter3D" irá gravar os dados das variáveis no gráfico, o "s" na função é o tamanho dos pontos a serem marcados.

Para criar superfícies em 3d, é recomendado que se crie uma função para calcular os valores vindos de uma função matemática que defina um valor "z". Isso facilita a criação do gráfico. Após isso, devemos definir valores para x e y, então temos o código manipulanto a biblioteca numpy:

```
x = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
y = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
```

A função linspace acima irá gerar 10 valores entre -5 e 5 para mais detalhes segue a documentação da biblioteca: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html

Com isso, agora podemos começar a momntar propriamente a superfície. Para isso devemos usar outra função da biblioteca numpy que irá repetir os valores de cada eixo, resultando em um grid:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

Após isso, devemos calcular os valores de Z com a função montada no início, para isso basta passar os valores das variaveis X e Y para a função, segue exemplo:

```
Z = funcao_exemploz(X,Y)
```

Agora, é possível plotarmos o gráfico com a superfície:

```
grap = plt.axes(projection='3d')
grap.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, color = '')
```

Também, é possível plotar o grafico com um espaçamento entre os pontos, podendo facilitar a visualização:

```
grap.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z, color ='', linewidth = '')
```

Lembrando que é possível customizar o gráfico normalmente, igual no 2d.
Bem como rotacionar o gráfico e colocar nomes nos eixos:

```
grap.view_init(45,0)
grap.set_xlabel('x')
grap.set_ylabel('y')
grap.set_zlabel('z')
```

É valido resaltar que em grap.view_init() os valores estão em graus. O primieiro valor é o angulo de elevação da vista e o segundo o  de rotação.